# Obtain HTTP Header in Python

Tags: php, python, openam

I have set up OpenAm as authentication module for my python server. In front of my python server is Apache http server working as reverse proxy. OPenAM agent was installed on the Apache http server. Every call to the Apache http server was first redirected to OpenAm server for authentication, and OpenAm will forward some user attributes in http head to the Apache server  after authentication. Using php code, I could easily dump contents from the header. So my question is: Is there any way I could retrieve these information from http head in my python server?

Comment: What is the `python server`?  Is this a web framework like django, flask, etc.  Or is this something else?

Comment: It is twisted web server underneath, but they did modification heavily. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably reuse this: https://github.com/jathanism/python-opensso

Comment: Thanks for your lead. However, I am using certificate/ocsp validation instead of user name and passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://modpython.org/live/mod_python-3.3.1/doc-html/pyapi-mprequest-mem.html

headers_in

of course you have to configure the agent to inject the needed headers, see my reply on openam alias.

Comment: Bernhard, Thank you for pointing me to mod_python. Though it is not my favorite solution, it works. Thanks again.